# Why django redis cache cannot get the data in redis

Tags: django, redis, django-redis

My cache settings:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django_redis.cache.RedisCache',
        'LOCATION': 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/1',
        'OPTIONS': {
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
        },
    }
}
```

the host is 127.0.0.1, the port is 6379 and database is 1.

I want to add the data by using `redis_connection` like this:

```
from django_redis import get_redis_connection

redis_conn = get_redis_connection('default')
redis_conn.set('somekey', 'somevalue')
```

So the redis database has the data now, I can get it by:

```
redis_conn.get('somekey')
```

but I couldn't get it by `django.core.cache.cache`, although data exists in the database:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
cache.get('somekey')  #return None
```

If I must use conn to set data and use cache to get data, what should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Django cache adds a prefix to cache keys. By default, this depends on [`KEY_PREFIX`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#key-prefix) and [`VERSION`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#version) in your `CACHES` settings. You can also customise the behaviour by using a custom [`KEY_FUNCTION`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#key-function).

You can use the `make_key` method to find out the full cache key:

```
>>> from django.core.cache import cache
>>> cache.make_key('somekey')
':1:somekey'
```

You can use this full key when you call `redis_conn.set()`.

As you pointed out in the comments, there is a second difficulty. Django-redis [serializes the cache values](https://niwinz.github.io/django-redis/latest/#_pluggable_serializer). By default it uses Python pickle but there is also a JSON serializer available or you can choose your own.

When you write to the cache using `redis_conn.set()`, you will have to serialize the data in the same way so that django-redis can read it.

Comment: Thx, it helps a lot.  When I set an int value, it works. But when my value's type is string or dict, I must encode my value otherwise the program could raise exception.

Comment: That's a good point. I've updated the answer with a note about the serializers.